# keep getting a argumentOutOfRangeExceptions when running my code vb.net

Tags: winforms, vb.net-2010, tablelayoutpanel

i keep running in this issue where it will jump out of the for statements that generate the table, I've been pouring over the code for a better part of three hours and i cannot find what is going wrong so i think i need another pair of eyes.

`Shared Function DrawGrid() As TableLayoutPanel

    Dim dayNames As New ArrayList

    dayNames.Add("Monday")

    dayNames.Add("Tuesday")

    dayNames.Add("Wednesday")

    dayNames.Add("Thursday")

    dayNames.Add("Friday")

    dayNames.Add("Saturday")

    dayNames.Add("Sunday")

    Dim hour As Integer = 8

    Dim minute As Integer = 0

    Dim timeType As String = "AM"

    Dim dayLength As Integer = 12

    Dim timetable As New TableLayoutPanel

    timetable.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Inset`

```
'Loops through days one at a time this creates the labels and adds them for reference by the user but is not needed for the timetable creation
For days As Integer = 0 To 7
    timetable.ColumnCount += 1
    timetable.RowCount += 1
    If days > 0 Then
        Dim NamePos As New TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(days, 0)
        Dim lblDay As New Label

        lblDay.Text = CStr(dayNames.Item(days))

        timetable.SetCellPosition(lblDay, NamePos)
        timetable.Controls.Add(lblDay)
    End If

    For time As Integer = 0 To dayLength
        Dim rowPos As New TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(days, time)
        Dim lblTime As New Label
        Dim timeString As String
        timetable.RowCount += 1
        If days = 0 Then
            minute += 6
            If minute = 6 Then
                minute = 0
                hour += 1

            End If
            If hour = 13 Then
                hour = 1
                timeType = "PM"
            End If
            timeString = "Time is " & hour & ":" & minute & "0 " & timeType
            lblTime.Text = timeString

            timetable.SetCellPosition(lblTime, rowPos)

            timetable.Controls.Add(lblTime)
            timetable.Visible = True

        End If


    Next
Next
timetable.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddColumns
timetable.AutoSize = True
MessageBox.Show("Working")
Return timetable
```

End Function

Comment: Dayname has only 7 items, but you are iterating on it 8 times, so you are getting an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to add a breakpoint to the For loop to see at what point error is being generated? If so check what the local variable values are just before it throws the exception.

An out of range exception can be because you are trying to access an array/collection item that doesn't exist.

For instance myArray(4) has 5 items, if I try to access myArray(5) I will get an out of range exception, because the index starts at 0.

Comment: Well what you are describing is the definition of an OOR exception. Im pretty sure he is getting it because he doesnt know how the for loop in VB.net works.

Comment: ahh i get it yeh im pretty sure its the array thats causing the problem as thats where its cutting out thanks for the help

Comment: Yes I would agree, the line that would be throwing the exception is   lblDay.Text = CStr(dayNames.Item(days)) as it is trying to to access the 8th item in the arraylist that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` in `VB.NET` is inclusive, eg :

```
            For i = 0 To 5
                Debug.WriteLine(i)' outputs : 0,1,2,3,4,5
            Next
```

So you might want to use some `-1` when looping.

This for example iterates 8 times, while you are wanting to iterate only 7 times (unless in your country you have 8 days in a week)

```
For days As Integer = 0 To 7
```

Here is a possible correction :

```
      For days As Integer = 0 To 6
            timetable.ColumnCount += 1
            timetable.RowCount += 1
            If days > 0 Then
                Dim NamePos As New TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(days, 0)
                Dim lblDay As New Label

                lblDay.Text = CStr(dayNames.Item(days))

                timetable.SetCellPosition(lblDay, NamePos)
                timetable.Controls.Add(lblDay)
            End If

            For time As Integer = 0 To dayLength - 1
                Dim rowPos As New TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(days, time)
                Dim lblTime As New Label
                Dim timeString As String
                timetable.RowCount += 1
                If days = 0 Then
                    Minute += 6
                    If Minute() = 6 Then
                        Minute = 0
                        Hour += 1

                    End If
                    If Hour() = 13 Then
                        Hour = 1
                        timeType = "PM"
                    End If
                    timeString = "Time is " & Hour() & ":" & Minute() & "0 " & timeType
                    lblTime.Text = timeString

                    timetable.SetCellPosition(lblTime, rowPos)

                    timetable.Controls.Add(lblTime)
                    timetable.Visible = True

                End If


            Next
        Next
```

Comment: the reason for 8 is because the  first column have the time labels in it

Comment: Well, you might want to start iterating from 1 then, instead of 0 ? Because i still cant see why you are iterating 8 times, when a week only has 7 days.